# How to fix the bot configuration when migrating settings form .bot file to appsettings

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, appsettings

I ran into a problem when trying to deploy my bot to Azure. The following error was given when I tried to create the Azure resources: `error: InvalidBotData, message: Version: Bot Version has an invalid value.` I dug around a little bit and found the that my bot is version 4.3 while now you need 4.4 to deploy…

I found that Mircosoft already has a solution for the problem found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/bot-service/bot-file-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp I followed the steps, I also changed the way QnAmaker and Luis are called. But when I run the application I get the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'VacancyBot.VacancyBot.Services.BotServices' while attempting to activate 'VacancyBot.VacancyBotBot'.`
I realized that the bot was not being added anywhere anymore so I tried adding it with `services.AddSingleton<VacancyBotBot>()` but that did not work. Adding it as an Transient also does not work.

The part that normally adds the bot is this:

```
var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("botFileSecret")?.Value;
var botFilePath = Configuration.GetSection("botFilePath")?.Value;

var botConfig = BotConfiguration.Load(botFilePath ?? @".\nlp-with-luis.bot", secretKey);
services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));

var connectedServices = new BotServices(botConfig);
services.AddSingleton(sp => connectedServices);
```

But this does not work anymore because, as aspected, the .\nlp-with-luis.bot cannot be found. (I did not delete the .bot file for real yet, but it doesn't use it anymore now I guess?).

I was wondering if anybody happens to know how to add the bot, or alter the `BotConfiguration` in a way that it works again. I really hope this is possible! If someone needs to see more code please say so and I will try to provide it (:

I forgot to add that I tried putting back `"botFilePath": "VacancyBot.bot",
  "botFileSecret": "",` in the appsettings file, but results into getting the same error in Azure again...

Comment: the .Bot file is still used as far as I am aware, I haven't removed it from any of my code and it deploys as expected.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt but did you change the configuration or remove the path from the appsettings.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .bot file can still be used, but it looks like you're trying to use a combination of .bot file and appsettings.json. Let's get you straightened out.

Starting with appsettings.json: You no longer need `botFilePath` or `botFileSecret`. Instead, structure your appsettings.json like below:

```
{
  "MicrosoftAppId": "",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "",
  "LuisAppId": "",
  "LuisAPIKey": "",
  "LuisAPIHostName": ""
}
```

The `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` are now pulled in through a ConfigurationCredentialProvider.cs file, which will later be added as a singleton in Startup.cs. The ConfigurationCredentialProvider should look like below:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace CoreBot1
{
    public class ConfigurationCredentialProvider : SimpleCredentialProvider
    {
        public ConfigurationCredentialProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
            : base(configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"])
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Short, sweet and to the point. Finally, structure your startup.cs like below, to add both the bot and the ICredentialProvider:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using CoreBot1.Bots;
using CoreBot1.Dialogs;

namespace CoreBot1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup()
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
            services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

            // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
            services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

            // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
            services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

            // The Dialog that will be run by the bot.
            services.AddSingleton<MainDialog>();

            // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
            services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogAndWelcomeBot<MainDialog>>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem seemed to be that I was missing the `ConfigurationCredentialProvider` so nothing happened to the Mircosoft -appid or -password either.. So this fixed it (: